# Dividing lists in Svelte

Tags: list, svelte, line-breaks

I had a recent urge to play with reading and formatting a GEDCOM (Genealogy) file and I'm using Svelte to accomplish this. But I'm stuck on a problem I'm not quite sure the best way to do it. Extracted from the GEDCOM file is a collection of names sorted by surnames. Let's say it's this:

```
Adams, John
Anderson, Neo
Cash, Johnny
Clapton, Eric
Cross, Christopher
Denver, John
```

The real list is quite a bit bigger and needs indicators for the letters of the alphabet. Essentially, I want to have the following as output:

```
Names starting with A:
Adams, John; Anderson, Neo;

Names starting with C:
Cash, Johnny; Clapton, Eric; Cross, Christopher;

Names starting with D:
Denver, John;
```

I have no problem spewing out the list. Svelte makes that easy enough. What I haven't figured out yet is how to interject the breaks. Each thing I've tried or thought about seems to be flawed. As far as I can tell, there's no good way to simply alter a variable as a loop progresses and there doesn't seem to be a way to get the previous item in the loop. Any suggestions for an approach?
I currently have this, but where to begin injecting the header?

```
    {#each data.sort(compare) as n }
        {#if n.ReverseName }
            {n.ReverseName}  
        {/if}
    {/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to ask yourself, "what is the format of the data output I want to obtain?". Considering your question and your objective to be able to loop through the output, you'd probably want the following structure:

```
output = [
  [array of names starting with A, if any],
  [array of names starting with B, if any],
  etc.
]
```

I believe a relatively straightforward way to achieve this is with a reducer:

```js
// start with sorting the input array so names are
// already properly sorted before being input to our reducer
const output = input.sort().reduce((acc, current) => {
  // if the accumulator is an empty array,
  // return the current value in a new sub array
  // (the very first name pushed into the very first sub array)
  if (acc.length === 0) {
    return [ [ current ] ];
  }
  // otherwise, if the initial of the first name in
  // the current (i.e. last created) sub array matches
  // the initial of the current value, add that current
  // value to the current sub array
  const [ currentSub ] = acc.slice(-1);
  if (currentSub[0].charAt(0) === current.charAt(0)) {
    return [ ...acc.slice(0, -1), [ ...currentSub, current ] ]; 
  }
  // else add a new sub array and initialise it with the current value
  return [ ...acc, [ current ] ];
}, []); // initialise with an empty array
```

The output array will have the desired shape `[ [names starting with A, if any], [names starting with B, if any], ... ]` and all that's left is for you to iterate through that output array:

```html
{#each output as letterArray}
  <p>Names starting with <strong>{letterArray[0].charAt(0)}</strong>:</p>
  <p>{letterArray.join('; ')}</p>
{/each}
```

Or if you want to iterate over individual names, add an inner `each` block that iterates over `letterArray`. Many possibilities exist once your data is shaped the way you want it to be.

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e96a307e46384a95a16ac76758f41680?version=3.55.1)

##### Edit:

If `input` is dynamic (i.e. it is updated through the life of the component, either via a `fetch` or because it is received as a prop that might get updated), you can keep `output` automatically updated by turning its declaration into reactive code:

```html
$: output = input.sort().reduce(...same code as above...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a go and see what I get.